# Angularjs $http post promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, angularjs-http

I try to use the promise respond from a $http.post, to get back the new ID of the record as integer and use it for the next $http.post. I used [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/616717) for help but it still don´t work.

```
var streckenId;
var trackpunktId;

var getStreckeID = function () {
  $http.post(dbStrecke, {"ort": location, "distanz": km}).then(function (response) {
    streckenId = response.data;
    console.log("ID (then): " + streckenId); // return ID
  });
  return streckenId;
};

streckenId = getStreckeID();
console.log("StreckeID:" + streckenId); //return undefined
```

The last console.log still say that "streckenId" is undefined.

Comment: You didn't read the answer to the question very well, you are still trying to use something that hasn't been set yet.

Comment: are you kidding me? I have try to solve with the thread above, but it don´t work, so I still get no help? great community!!

Comment: It does work, you simply implemented it wrong.

Comment: yeah so tell me what did I do wrong? I´ve read the answers and tried different things, but nothing worked, so I ask here for advance...

Answer (score 0):

modify you code such this

```
 var streckenId;
 var trackpunktId;

 var getStreckeID = function () {
    return $http.post(dbStrecke, {"ort": location, "distanz": km});
 };

 getStreckeID().then(function(response) {
    streckenId = response.data;
    console.log("ID (then): " + streckenId); // return ID
 });
```

Data from server will be available only when promise is resolved .
So assignment will be performed after resolving the promise . Otherwise `streckenId` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still don´t work. the console.log outside from then gives an undefined

Comment: did you check what comes with response ?

Comment: yes, the response in the .then() {} gives back the right ID

Comment: the problem is, that I need the response outside the .then() block